# Multithreading on arrays / Do I need locking mechanisms here?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-agnostic

I am writing a Multithreaded application. That application contains an array of length, lets say, 1000.

If I now would have two threads and I would make sure, that thread 1 will only access the elements 0-499 and thread 2 would only access elements 500-999, would I need a locking mechanism to protect the array or would that be fine.

Note: Only the content of the array will be changed during calculations! The array wont be moved, `memcpy`ed or in some other way altered than altering elements inside of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is perfectly fine! Those kind of strategies (melt together with a bunch of low level atomic primitives) are the basis for what's called *lock-free programming*.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there could be possible problems in implementing this solution. You have to strongly guarantee the properties, that you have mentioned.

1. Make sure, that your in memory data array never moves. You cannot rely on most `std` containers. Most of them could significantly change during modification. `std::map` are rebalancing inner trees and making some inner pointers invalid. `std::vector` sometimes reallocates the whole container when inserting.
2. Make sure that there is only one consumer and only one producer for any data, that you have. Each consumer have to store inner iterator in valid state to prevent reading same item twice, or skip some item. Each producer must put data in valid place, without possibility to overwrite existing, not read data.

Disobeying  of **any** of this rules makes you need to implement mutexes.